# Open .tdt files in Excel by default

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, file-extension

I routinely use Excel for TDT and other formats.  I've never had a problem getting Windows to open .tdt files in Excel by default; in Windows 7, it's right-click -> Open with -> Choose default program... -> Browse -> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office##\Excel.exe` -> Open.

However, I recently installed Excel 2013, and the above technique no longer works.  Even after navigating to Excel and hitting Open, Excel does not appear in the list of programs.

So I guess I need to add the association in the registry somewhere.  I see the list of extensions in HKCR, but the entry for CSV implies that Excel has special handling for that extension; anyway, copying the keys and value from .csv to .tdt has no impact.  I also see `HKCU\Software\Classes\.tdt` with a "Content Type" of "application/vnd.ms-excel", but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Finally, there's `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tdt\OpenWithList`.  There's a value for EXCEL.EXE and several others, but only two of these (7-Zip and Notepad++) appear in the GUI.  I *can* choose either of these two apps, however it doesn't seem to have changed the content of either registry key, so there's no obvious entry to change.

Googling around, I see plenty of discussions about using the GUI, but the registry doesn't come up as often, and no two seem to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to right-click the TDT file, click "Properties", and under the General Tab where it says "Open with:", click the "Change". Browse to the location in Program Files > Office > Office[x] > excel.exe

That should work.

I would also try changing it to something else (Notepad, for example), reboot, and then change back to Excel - see if that works.

Comment: This should work. I wouldn't bother messing with the registry entries. Actually, I'd recommend against it for OP unless he really knows what he's doing.

Comment: No, the Properties tab doesn't work any better than the right-click | Open with menu.  I've rebooted since setting it to Notepad++, with no change.

Comment: Did it work when you set it to Notepad++? What about after setting it back to Excel and then rebooting again?

Comment: It works with Notepad++, that is files now open in Notepad++ by default.  The issue is that I *can't* set the default to Excel, as it does not appear in the menu even after browsing to the actual .exe.